# Присутствует ли в предложении деепричастный оборот и нужна ли запятая?

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

"Вращая опорные винты, вывести инклинометр в вертикальное положение."

Answer (score 1):

**Вращая опорные винты**, вывести инклинометр в вертикальное положение.

Обособление деепричастного оборота.

В данном предложении инфинитив "вывести" соответствует форме повелительного наклонения  "выведите" и относится к одному действующему лицу.